# bash: let a process run in background, restart if required, but receive CTRL-C from the parent script

Tags: shell, bash-scripting, kill

I'm using `livestreamer` and `ffmpeg` to grab images from a live stream at 0.1 fps:

```
livestreamer --player "ffmpeg -i" --player-args "{filename} -vf fps=1/10 out%04d.png" https://www.ustream.tv/channel/number worst
```

I couldn't get ffmpeg to overwrite its output, so it keeps creating new files with the `out%04d.png` pattern. This is fine, I can keep track of the newest out file and delete old ones. However, the `livestreamer` process sometimes exits for various reasons and I'd like to restart it automatically as long as I want it to run.

An attempt using a subshell didn't react to CTRL-C as I expected because the signal is not passed on the subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash

( while true; do
  livestreamer --player "ffmpeg -i" --player-args "{filename} -vf fps=0.1 out%04d.png" https://www.ustream.tv/channel/number worst
done ) &

while true; do
  newestImage=${code to find newest image}
  postProcess $newestImage
  deleteOldImages
  sleep 5
done
```

When I send `SIGINT` to above script, the subshell stays alive even when I close the shell in which I started the parent script. The output directory is flooded with new files while the code that is supposed to delete them is not running any more. A `trap` didn't help either:

```
trap "kill $SUBSHELL_PID" SIGINT

( ... ) & # subshell as above
SUBSHELL_PID=&!
```

With that I wasn't even able to interrupt the parent script. Obviously, I'm not experienced with signal handling in bash at all, so I'm happy about any advice that gets me forward. I need to restart the frame grabber as long as the parent script is running, and keep track of old files in order to delete them.

Edit: Might the subshell be a bad idea in the first place? Can I somehow launch `livestreamer` in the background and either kill it when I want, or restart it when it exited by itself?

Comment: Once you know the PID of the subshell, with a single grep or awk command you can get which livestreamer processes were started by that and kill only those livestreamer(s) in the trap.

Answer (score 1):

Kill livestreamer itself.

```
trap "killall livestreamer" SIGINT
```

Comment: Does that not kill any instances of `livestreamer` outside of my parent script? I'm not having any yet, but I might in the future

Comment: Your whole solution is a quick dirty hack. In the future write a correct error handling instead of pressing ctrl-c yourself a dozen times a day.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, and I'm willing to improve it. Your comment, however, is not helpful in that respect, and does not answer the question I have regarding your answer.